# What is the solo instrument played in "Immolation" from the Schindler's List soundtrack?

Tags: identify-this-instrument

There is an interesting sounding instrument playing a solo a the 3 minute mark of "Immolation (With Our Lives, We Give Life)" from the Schindler's List soundtrack.  It sounds like a woodwind instrument but not one I recognise.  The same instrument is used on the theme for "White Lotus" season two although that one is sampled.  I would love to know what it is!

Comment: Unfortunatley off-topic, the correct tag would have been identify-this-instrument. I'd also guess that it is some kind of flute, but sounds not breathy enough for pan flute, which would have been my guess otherwise.

Comment: @MFB: It's a tenor recorder with keys if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I think you're right.  I just listened to some other example of the tenor recorder and it sounds the same.  The only difference is the degree of portamento achieved in the Schindler's List piece, but I guess that's possible...?